# can't understand what Base class is in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a code of the type

```
Module Themes
  class NewTheme < Themes::Base
    def1
    end

    def2
    end
  end
end
```

when i try to create an instance of new theme with Themes::NewTheme.instance the instance is empty, what is wrong here? Also what is ::Base? I can't find a defincition anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be saying `NewTheme.new` instead of `Themes::NewTheme` to instanciate your class.

As for a base class, it's just a sort of 'final' parent class - a class that has no parent class, but has children classes (perhaps just a few, or many).  Here's an example from [ActiveRecord::Base](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html)

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Uses an integer of seconds to hold the length of the song

  def length=(minutes)
    write_attribute(:length, minutes.to_i * 60)
  end

  def length
    read_attribute(:length) / 60
  end
end
```

In this case, the class `Song` is getting all of the methods defined in ActiveRecord::Base 'for free'

Comment: sadly NewTheme.New didn't help. thanks for the explanation on ::Base though!